# How to create a sliding animation on menu hover with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, jquery-animate

I've seen this on plenty of websites but I'm not sure if I'll be able to explain it.

Sometimes there are sliding elements in navigation, just like arrow under menu items that is sliding when user hovers over different menu links etc.

Here's a simple menu:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link number 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link something 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

And some jQuery (I know I'll be able to get the same effect with simple css :hover):

```
jQuery('ul li a').hover(function() {
    jQuery('a').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Also, working jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8EvhK/

Buttons background becomes red on hover. I want this background to slide and transform (width) between these buttons as I hover.

How to do something like that? I've been looking for tutorials, but no luck.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` most of the time. ie. `$("a").removeClass("active");`

Comment: By the way, a hover effect like your example should always be done with CSS but not with Javascript.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Add an element to the menu using jquery's `append`.

   ```
   $('ul').append('<div id="slider"></div>');
   ```
2. On `hover` of any menu item, `animate` this new element to the horizontal `position` and `width` of the menu item which fired the event.

   ```
   $('ul li a').hover(function(){

       var left = $(this).parent().position().left;
       var width = $(this).width();

       $('#slider').stop().animate({
           'left' : left,
           'width' : width
       });
   });
   ```
3. Reset the slider to its initially state.

   ```
   var left = $('ul li:first-child a').parent().position().left;
   var width = $('ul li:first-child a').width();
   $('#slider').css({'left' : left, 'width' : width});
   ```
4. Add some CSS.

   ```
   #slider {
       position:absolute;
       top: -5px;
       left: 0;
       height: 100%;
       width: 0;
       padding: 5px 15px;
       background-color: #f00;
       z-index:-1;
   }
   ```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wPQa/2/

Comment: Fix:
http://jsfiddle.net/5wPQa/1/  
Because the border has a width of 1px, you need to add 1px to the left

Comment: @Puyol: Well spotted! I edited my answer with another version fixing it via CSS.

Comment: Anytime. You could change the jquery event `hover` to `mouseenter` for a better performance because `hover` fired also if the mouse leaves the element which isn't necessary here. But it doesn't matter because this script isn't performance related.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this effect with [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions):

```
ul li {
    display:block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    width:50%;
    -moz-transition: width 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: width 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: width 1s; /* Opera */
}

ul li:hover{
    width:100%;
}
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/MaJac89/8EvhK/5/).